# How to change file association for .iso files?

Tags: iso-image, file-association

I have some software tools in iso format. by default they are associated with the window disc burning utility. I want to change the association of iso files so that they are installed when I click on the files. (I have installed some applications in this way, like visual studio) How I would be able to do it?
Moreover, I need this on both windows 7 and windows XP.

Comment: You can't. ISO files by default is a kind of container files. It will not execute. There may be installer files inside the ISO files that you can run and install, but Windows by default will not recognize ISO file as something that it can execute and run. There may be some 3rd party that automatically mount the ISO files (so you have visibility of the content of the ISO files) and then run the obvious setup.exe (or install.exe) but I'm not aware of one. About changing the association of .ISO with some other programs, check the answer from Jeremy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are programmes to emulate a fake optical drive, and mount iso images as if they are optical disks. if you in the past have clicked some iso image and immediately some software install dialogue showed up, you must have some optical drive emulation programme enabled on your machine. check for your local filesystem for such programme.

Comment: Like Windows 8 :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 - click "start" and "Control Panel"  Click "Default Programs", then "associate a file type or protocol with a program" you can the set the program you want with the file type.

Comment: "I want to change the association of iso files so that they are installed when I click on the files." - You haven't addressed this part of the question at all.